# environments.txt file in dot conda folder and visual studio code python extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I have several conda installed on my computer. (anaconda/miniconda/conda from Julia) and in `$HOME/.conda` folder, there is a file environments.txt that has some of these listed. Does anyone know which process produced this environments.txt file?

I am asking because from time to time Visual Studio Code were confusing the environment names. VS code could select correct python version, but sometimes mistaken the environment name from 'base' to 'anaconda3', which could cause Jupyter server failed to start.

By manually deleting this file, vs code can work properly again. I wanted to find the source of this file and get a better solution for this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think they just clobber it, i.e., all Conda instances edit this. [It's an openly complained about issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8804).

Comment: As @merv alluded to, the file is generated and managed by conda. The extension just reads it to try and avoid running `conda list` which is a very slow operation.